# Using sed to match multiple possible environments in a file

Tags: sed

I have some files numbered 01 to 24 that contain things like

```
\begin{thm}
  blah blah blah
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}
  blah blah blah
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}
  blah blah blah
\end{prop}
```

inside of them and I want to extract every one of these matches from the file (together with the 'blah blah blah' of course). So I was happily using

```
sed -n '/\\begin{FOO}/,/\\end{FOO}/p' ./*.tex >> newfile.txt
```

and running the above with `FOO` replaced by `thm` then `lem` then `prop`. But I realised I am stupid because the order is all mixed up now in `newfile.txt` in the sense that all the `\begin{thm}...\end{thm}` precede all the `begin{lem}...\end{lem}` precede all the `begin{prop}...\end{prop}` even if they follow one another in one of the files say, but I want to keep them in the order that they appear in the files.

> **Question:** How can I get `sed` to extract all of these case at once, and thus preserve the order that they appear in the files?

Comment: Is `\end{FOO}` always on the same line as `\begin{FOO}`? That's unusual.

Comment: It is not always on the same line, I guess I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you need to get all ranges at once. You can do it with following `sed` construction:

```
sed -n '/\\begin{FOO}/,/\\end{FOO}/p;
        /\\begin{FOO1}/,/\\end{FOO1}/p;
        /\\begin{FOO2}/,/\\end{FOO2}/p;' ./*.tex >> newfile.txt
```

where FOO == thm, FOO1 == lem, FOO2 == prop.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have needlessly complicated things, if these are all single lines, all you need is

```
sed -n '/\\begin{FOO}/p' >> newfile.txt
```

Not sure why you are also matching the `\end` unless you want to exclude any text that comes afterwards (but your `sed` command won't).

Anyway, an easier way would be to just use `grep` instead:

```
grep -P '\\begin\{(thm|prop|lem)\}' *tex
```

Or, in `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\\begin{thm}/p; /\\begin{prop}/p; /\\begin{lem}/p' *tex
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\\begin{thm|lem|prop}/' *tex
```

Comment: I think what the question omits is that the `\end{FOO}` may be (and usually is) on a different line from `\begin{FOO}`.

Comment: As above, this won't work for me because they don't appear on the same line, I guess I should have made this more clear in the statement.